# Creating a variable for the text node of each element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a variable for each element in a set. I have an HTML structure like this:

```
<div id="notes">
    <p>Example Text 1</p>
    <p>Example Text 2</p>
    <p>Example Text 3</p>
</div>
```

I want to store the text of each of the elements in a separate variable. In this case the elements are dynamically generated, so sometimes there are 2 elements, sometimes there are more.

What I have tried so far:

```
var $counter= 0;
var variableNote = {};
$('#notes p').each(function(){
   $counter += 1;
   variableNote["newNote"+$counter] = $("#notes p").text();
   console.log(newNote1);
});
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You're not creating variables, you're just creating object properties. Use `console.log(variableNote["newNote1"]);`

Answer (score 3):

Object properties are not variables. To access them you need to refer to the object.

Also, you're not using the current element of the iteration in your loop.

```
var variableNote = {};

$('#notes p').each(function(index) {
    variableNote["newNote" + (index+1)] = $(this).text();
});

console.log(variableNote["newNote1"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var variableNote = {};
$('#notes p').each(
  (i,e) => variableNote["newNote" +(i+1)] = $(e).text()
);

console.log( variableNote );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="notes">
    <p>Example Text 1</p>
    <p>Example Text 2</p>
    <p>Example Text 3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by finding the elements and reducing them into a single object.

```js
//lookup the p tags, and reduce them to a single object
var variableNotes = $('#notes p').get().reduce(function(notes, note, index){
  notes['newNote'+ ++index] = note.innerText;
  return notes;
}, {});

console.log(variableNotes);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="notes">
    <p>Example Text 1</p>
    <p>Example Text 2</p>
    <p>Example Text 3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using vanilla javascript

```js
var variableNotes = [...document.querySelectorAll("#notes p")].reduce((noteList, note, i)=>{
  noteList['newNote'+ (i +1)] = note.innerText;
  return noteList;
}, {});

console.log(variableNotes);
```

```html
<div id="notes">
    <p>Example Text 1</p>
    <p>Example Text 2</p>
    <p>Example Text 3</p>
</div>
```